# Generating random values

Tags: haskell

I'm getting stuck on generating some normally distributed random variables. I am using the mwc-random package.

In GHCI, I can do this:

```
gen <- create
normal 0 1 gen
```

and on my machine this produces:

```
-0.8077385934202513
```

In my program, I only want to create the generator once and then repeatedly use that to generate many random value for my simulation so I did this:

```
createGenerator :: PrimMonad m => m (Gen (PrimState m))                                              
createGenerator = do                                                                                 
  gen <- create                                                                                      
  return gen

returnPRNG :: PrimMonad m => Int -> Int -> m Double                                             
returnPRNG 0 1 =  normal 0 1 createGenerator
```

But I get an error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘PrimState m’ with ‘Gen (PrimState Gen)’
 Expected type: Gen (PrimState m) 
   Actual type: Gen (Gen (PrimState Gen))
```

I'm probably not doing this idiomatically so any help in that area would be great also.

Comment: Firstly, `createGenerator` is exactly the same as `create` - the extra `return` in there does nothing. You probably want `create >>= normal 0 1` - although the definition of `returnPRNG` is also very strange, it only works for the inputs 0 and 1, if that is actually the desired behaviour, why not just *not* have inputs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you want to create your generator only once than your the first part should look like this:

```
createGenerator :: PrimMonad m => m (Gen (PrimState m))
createGenerator = gen

...

main = do
    ...
    myGen <- createGenerator
```

(notice how you don't really do anything but give `gen` another name?)

and then you have to pass the generator around:

```
returnPRNG :: PrimMonad m => Double -> Double -> Gen (PrimState m) -> m Double
returnPRNG a b gen =  normal a b gen
```

which is of course just (again just another name)

```
returnPRNG = normal
```

(notice that you have to pass `Double`s to  [`normal`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mwc-random-0.13.4.0/docs/System-Random-MWC-Distributions.html#v:normal) - so assuming the extra arguments are really for that you have to use those)

the usage in your program will look like this:

```
main = do
    ...
    myGenen <- createGenerator
    ...
    rndVal1 <- returnPRNG 0 1 myGen
    rndVal2 <- returnPRNG 0 1 myGen
```

and as noticed that's really just

```
main = do
    ...
    myGen <- gen
    ...
    rndVal1 <- normal 0 1 myGen
    rndVal2 <- normal 0 1 myGen
```

Comment: If you don't want to have to fill in the `myGen` argument everywhere, you could define `returnPRNG` as having a `MonadReader` constraint.